# Showing 2 sheets/panels - one-after-the-other

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsalert

I'm trying to show 2 sheets (panels) one after the other. However, it looks like the first sheet doesn't have enough time to close before the second one shows up - so, it ends up in quite a mess.

Here's my code...

**Macros**

```
#define DRK_ALERT_YESNO_SHOW(X,Y,W) \
NSAlert* yesnoAlert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:X \
defaultButton:@"Yes" \
alternateButton:@"No" \
otherButton:nil \
informativeTextWithFormat:Y]; \
[yesnoAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:[[NSApp delegate] window] \
modalDelegate:self \
didEndSelector:W \
contextInfo:nil];

// Open File Sheet

#define DRK_OPENFILE_SHEET_BEGIN(X,Y,Z,A) NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];\
[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection: NO];\
[openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];\
[openPanel setCanCreateDirectories:NO];\
[openPanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];\
[openPanel setShowsHiddenFiles:YES];\
[openPanel setPrompt:Y];\
[openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:A];\
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:X completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {\
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {\
        NSString* Z = [openPanel filename];

#define DRK_OPENFILE_SHEET_END }\
}];
```

**Actual code**

```
- (IBAction)openDo:(id)sender {

    DRK_ALERT_YESNO_SHOW(@"Are you sure you want to discard changes?",
                         @"You may lose any changes you have made to your current projects.",
                         @selector(shouldOpenDo:code:context:));

}

- (void)shouldOpenDo:(NSAlert*)alert code:(int)choice context:(void *)context
{
    if (choice==NSAlertDefaultReturn)
    {
        DRK_OPENFILE_SHEET_BEGIN(([[NSApp delegate] window]), @"Open Project", filename,(@[@"txt"]));

        // Yep, we can now open the file: filename

        DRK_OPENFILE_SHEET_END
    }
    else
    {
        // nope, don't open anything
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so that's all it took :

```
[[alert window] orderOut:nil];
```

just before `DRK_OPENFILE_SHEET_BEGIN`.